# Should I use another form instead of W-2 in case of foreign earned income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, foreign-income, form-1040

I am a US/Dutch dual citizen living and working in the Netherlands permanently. I'm filing my tax return over 2019, and for the first time.

**Line 1 asks me to attach form(s) W-2**, but of course I can't, as I've only earned foreign income from by job in the Netherlands. Is there another form I should use, or should I attach my (annual) payslip?

---

(I also used form 2555, for the **Foreign Earned Income Exclusion**, in which I stated my employer's name and address. So I can imagine that even without an alternative to W-2, the IRS has enough information to fact-check my return if they want to.)